# Parsing an XML Feed with jQuery - cross domain (jsonp)

Tags: jquery, xml, jsonp

How can I parse this XML feed using jQuery?

http://bit.ly/1cUJ1Dk

I need to retrieve the Open Value

This is what I have so far:

```
var xml = "http://bit.ly/1cUJ1Dk",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$sharePrice = $xml.find( 'field[name="open"]' );

// Add Opening Price to Div
$(".open").append( $sharePrice.text() );
```

PS. I'm accessing this from a different server, so need to circumvent same origin policy

Comment: See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) for that function: *Parses a string into an XML document*. That's a string of XML not a URI. You need to use Ajax. There are many tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send an HTTP GET request to retrieve the feed, and then parse it as XML data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    // Don't use URLs with redirection
    url: 'http://feeds1.mcgbfa.com/engine.asmx/get15MinDelayedPrices?CompanyKey=coronation&subfeed=0',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        console.log(xml.find('field[name="open"]'));
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Error');  
    }
});
```

If you see "Error" in your console and if the HTTP request is good, this means that the returned XML is not valid.

Also : it seems that the feed's server is slow.

Comment: I copied your code and get this error, "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{5f9bde66-c960-254f-a491-f93e414c9e71} Line Number 1, Column 1:^" could this be a timeout issue on my side.

Comment: Your error indicate that the same origin policy check is working, as mentioned by @Quentin. If you're not sending Ajax requests from the same server (you not mentioned this in your question), your request will always fail. More informations : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: ok thanks, is there a way around same origin policy or should i do it server side

Comment: If you are not the feed server owner (to use JSONP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP for a workaround), you should do it server side